# Is there a way to pass objects as a navigationParam?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic4

[image: This is a screenshot of the console log]

gotomsg & go2msg are the 2 objects I'm logging before I send them to the page to which I'm navigating.

```html
  goToMessagePage(itinerary) {
    let myItin = this.findMyItinerary(itinerary.id);
    console.log('gotomsg', myItin);
    console.log('go2Msg', itinerary);

    const navigationParam: NavigationExtras = {
      queryParams: {
        theirItinerary: itinerary,
        myItinerary: myItin
      }
    };
    this.router.navigate(['messages'], navigationParam);
  }
```

Once I navigate to the 'messages' page I get the 2 objects in [object Object] but then when I try to access any properties of the object like object.id i get 'undefined'.

```html
  constructor(public messageService: MessagesService,
              private route: ActivatedRoute) {

    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      this.theirItinerary = params['theirItinerary'];
      this.myItinerary = params['theirItinerary'];
      console.log('Myitinerary message', this.myItinerary.data());
      console.log('theirItin message', this.theirItinerary.data());
    });
  }
```

Is there a way to get the values of the objects passed as navigation parameters?

Comment: Check if [**NavigationExtras#state**](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras#state) works for you.

Comment: It wouldn't work for me.  So I just passed in each property from the object individually in the navigationParams.

Comment: Excuse me, can you explain why it wouldn't work for you?

Comment: It may have implemented it wrong...looking for examples of how it's actually implemented.

Comment: [**Check this demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-kzc5ga)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `JSON.stringify`

```
  goToMessagePage(itinerary) {
    let myItin = this.findMyItinerary(itinerary.id);
    console.log('gotomsg', myItin);
    console.log('go2Msg', itinerary);

    const navigationParam: NavigationExtras = {
      queryParams: {
        theirItinerary: itinerary,
        myItinerary: JSON.stringify(myItin),
      },
    };
    this.router.navigate(['messages'], navigationParam);
  }
```

Or use `state`

```
  goToMessagePage(itinerary) {
    let myItin = this.findMyItinerary(itinerary.id);
    console.log('gotomsg', myItin);
    console.log('go2Msg', itinerary);

    const navigationParam: NavigationExtras = {
      queryParams: {
        theirItinerary: itinerary,
      },
      state: {
        myItinerary: myItin,
      },
    };
    this.router.navigate(['messages'], navigationParam);
  }
```

---

messages component:

```
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
  ) {
    const navigation = this.router.getCurrentNavigation();
    console.log(navigation.extras.state);
  }
```